# Using Ruffus library in Python 2.7, just_print flag fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, pipeline, ruffus

I've got a ruffus pipeline in Python 2.7, but when I call it with `-n` or `--just_print` it still runs all the actual tasks instead of just printing the pipeline like it's supposed to. I:
* don't have a `-n` argument that would supercede the built-in (although I do have other command-line arguments)
* have a bunch of functions with `@transform()` or `@merge()` decorators
* end the pipeline with a `run_pipeline()` call

Has anyone else experienced this problem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of ruffus version 2.4, you can use the builtin [`ruffus.cmdline`](http://www.ruffus.org.uk/tutorials/new_tutorial/command_line.html) which stores the appropriate flags via the `cmdline.py` module that uses `argparse`, for example:

```
from ruffus import *
parser = cmdline.get_argparse(description='Example pipeline')
options = parser.parse_args()

@originate("test_out.txt")
def run_testFunction(output):
        with open(output,"w") as f:
            f.write("it's working!\n")

cmdline.run(options)
```

Then run your pipeline from the terminal with a command like:

```
python script.py --verbose 6 --target_tasks run_testFunction --just_print
```

---

If you want to do this manually instead (which is necessary for older version of ruffus) you can call [`pipeline_printout()`](http://ruffus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline_functions.html#pipeline-functions-pipeline-printout) rather than [`pipeline_run()`](http://ruffus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline_functions.html#index-0), using `argparse` so that the `--just_print` flag leads to the appropriate call, for example:

```
from ruffus import *
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example pipeline')
parser.add_argument('--just_print', dest='feature', action='store_true')
parser.set_defaults(feature=False)
args = parser.parse_args()

@originate("test_out.txt")
def run_testFunction(output):
        with open(output,"w") as f:
            f.write("it's working!\n")

if args.feature:
    pipeline_printout(sys.stdout, run_testFunction, verbose = 6)
else:
    pipeline_run(run_testFunction, verbose = 6)
```

You would then run the command like:

```
python script.py --just_print
```

Comment: That's certainly a functional hack, but doesn't it defeat the purpose of ruffus having those built-in arguments? Or are the built-in arguments just suggestions?

Comment: @J.C.Szamosi There are no builtin arguments, you need to build your own constructs. I have seen code from the author of the ruffus package, he also does it something like this

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you! I think the documentation about predefined options (http://www.ruffus.org.uk/tutorials/new_tutorial/command_line.html) is a little misleading, so I'll get in touch with them about that.

Comment: @J.C.Szamosi Actually I was not aware of these new features in ruffus 2.4; see my updated answer and +1 for the question!

Comment: Ah! It was `cmdline.run(options)` that I was missing. I'm a little unsure about how that interacts with my normal habit of renaming argparse's variables for use in my scripts (i.e. `infile = options.i`), but I'll play with that.

Many thanks!